# Deleting duplicate JavaScript cookies based on the scope of domain and name

Tags: javascript, cookies

I recently changed the scope of some JavaScript cookies on our site. They were all scoped to the subdomain in which they were created. They are now scoped globally to the domain. The issue is I now have duplicate cookies that have different scopes.Is it possible to programatically eliminate the JavaScript cookies based on name and scope (domain)? Example:

cookieA --> domain=.mysite.com

cookieA--> domain=sub.mysite.com

cookieB --> domain=.mysite.com

cookieB --> domain=sub.mysite.com

I want to remove only cookies with domain = sub.mysite.com by name.

Comment: Does the older cookies interfere with your new ? ... If not, don't bother, they will be deleted when the user clean his cookies

Comment: Yes, because the browser will read the sub-domain scoped cookies over the globally scoped cookies. Also causing another issue on top of this.

Comment: So then remove them by setting their date 2 months back in time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [JavaScript Cookie library](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie).

If you want delete cookie named `cookieA`, which is set do domain `sub.mysite.com`, just run:

```
Cookies.remove("cookieA", {domain: "sub.mysite.com"})
```

This will remove `sub.mysite.com`'s `cookieA`, and leave `.mysite.com`'s `cookieA` untouched.

---

If you don't want to use this library, you can do it directly:

```
document.cookie = "cookieA=;domain=sub.mysite.com;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT"
```

Comment: Can this be done without using JavaScript Cookie Library?

Comment: @Gothdo this doesn't seem to work? I tried testing and the cookie expiration did NOT change?

Comment: @MichaelJohns How did you set that cookie? You have to use the same `path` and `domain` parameters.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem when changing our cookies to a global domain. Quite a lot of functionality was affected because duplicate cookies now exist (ex: `www.domain.com` and `.domain.com`). Since we deploy our website to different domains (dev, acc, prod) these issues were spread out across different domains.

Without going through all the pages to find issues cross domain, we've come up with a solution that doesn't require to know all the cookie names:

```
/*
 * @param c: window.Cookies
 * @doc https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie
 */
(function(c) {
    var arrCookies = document.cookie.split(/; */);
    var arrCookie;
    
    for (var cookie in arrCookies) {
        if (arrCookies.hasOwnProperty(cookie)) {
            arrCookie = arrCookies[cookie].split('=');
            c.remove(arrCookie[0], { domain: window.location.hostname });
            console.log('removing cookie ' + arrCookie[0] + ' on: ' + window.location.hostname);
        }
    }
}(window.Cookies));
```

This solution cleans up the active domain by using `window.location.hostname` and re-enables functionality for your previously set subdomain.